# DAO genérico com CDI erro = cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

Tags: java, java-8, cdi

Estou tentando implementar um DAO genérico com CDI. Aparentemente estou fazendo correto, porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

Este erro está me apontando para esta linha da minha classe Repository:

```
Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

**código interface IRepository**

```
package br.com.amarildo.repository;

import java.util.List;

public interface IRepository<T> {

    public T porId(Long id);

    public T guardar(T entity);

    public void alterar(T entity);

    public void remover(T entity);

    public List<T> todos();

}
```

**código Classe Repository**

```
package br.com.amarildo.repository;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

public class Repository<T> implements IRepository<T> {

    protected final EntityManager manager;
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Inject
    public Repository(EntityManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
        this.clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public T porId(Long id) {
        return manager.find(clazz, id);
    }

    public T guardar(T entity) {
        return this.manager.merge(entity);
    }

    public void alterar(T entity) {
        this.manager.merge(entity);
    }

    public void remover(T entity) {
        this.manager.remove(entity);
    }

    public List<T> todos() {
        TypedQuery<T> query = manager.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName(), clazz);
        List<T> resultList = query.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }

}
```

**código class TesteRepository**

```
package br.com.amarildo.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import br.com.amarildo.model.FuncionarioModel;


public class TesteRepository extends Repository<FuncionarioModel> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TesteRepository(EntityManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    public List<String> cargosQueContem(String cargo) {
        TypedQuery<String> query = super.manager.createQuery("select distinct cargo from FuncionarioModel " + "where upper(cargo) like upper(:cargo)", String.class);
        query.setParameter("cargo", "%" + cargo + "%");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

**código class FuncionarioController onde executo a TesteRepository**

```
package br.com.amarildo.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import br.com.amarildo.model.FuncionarioModel;
import br.com.amarildo.repository.TesteRepository;
import br.com.amarildo.util.NegocioException;
import br.com.amarildo.util.Transactional;

public class FuncionarioController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject 
    private TesteRepository funcionarioRepository;

    @Transactional
    public FuncionarioModel salvar(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) throws NegocioException {
        if (funcionarioModel.getCargo().isEmpty() ) {
            throw new NegocioException("Não é Possivel Salvar Funcionario sem Cargo");
        }
        return this.funcionarioRepository.guardar(funcionarioModel);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void atualizar(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) throws NegocioException {
        if (funcionarioModel.getCargo().isEmpty()) {
            throw new NegocioException("Não é possível fazer a Alteração campo cargo está vazio !");
        }
        this.funcionarioRepository.alterar(funcionarioModel);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void excluir(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) throws NegocioException {
        funcionarioModel = this.funcionarioRepository.porId(funcionarioModel.getCodigo());
        if (funcionarioModel.getCargo()== null) {
            throw new NegocioException("Não é possível excluir um Funcionario Demitido!");
        }
        this.funcionarioRepository.remover(funcionarioModel);
    }

}
```

Como resolver isso?

**Segue o erro que estou recebendo:**

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type TesteRepository with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private br.com.amarildo.controller.FuncionarioController.funcionarioRepository
  at br.com.amarildo.controller.FuncionarioController.funcionarioRepository(FuncionarioController.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
    ... 4 more

jun 29, 2017 10:26:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
```

**Obrigado a todos o erro Foi resolvido conforme abaixo: eu tinha que fazer a injeção no meu Construtor TesteRepository da class TesteRepository era só isso.**

```
@Inject
public TesteRepository(EntityManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Vejamos o que essa linha faz:

```
Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Primeiro, obtemos a superclasse, incluindo o tipo genérico:

```
getClass().getGenericSuperclass()
```

E então fazemos um cast para `ParameterizedType`, ou seja, um tipo que contém parâmetros genéricos.

Depois, pegamos o tipo do genérico:

```
[...].getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

E por fim, forçamos ele com um cast para uma classe:

```
Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) [...]
```

Ou seja, se você tiver um `BananaRepository extends Repository<Banana>`:

- O `getClass()` vai te dar o objeto que representa a class `BananaRepository`.
- O `.getGenericSuperclass()` var te dar `Repository<Banana>` - Observe que esse é um tipo genérico parametrizado, ou seja um `ParameterizedType`, logo podemos fazer o cast.
- O `.getActualTypeArguments[0]` vai pegar o tipo genérico do `Repository<Banana>`, ou seja `Banana`. Isso daí é uma classe, então o cast funciona.

Até aqui tudo certo, mas as coisas podem dar errado em outros cenários:

1. Se você tiver um `MyListRepository extends Repository<List<Banana>>`, o `getActualTypeArguments[0]` vai trazer `List<Banana>`, que é um tipo parametrizado, e não uma classe. O resultado disso vai ser um `ClasscastException`.
2. Se você tiver um `RawRepository extends Repository`, sem o tipo genérico, o `getGenericSuperclass()` vai retornar um objeto do tipo `Class`, e não um `ParameterizedType`. Outro `ClassCastException` aqui.
3. Se você tiver um `BananaPrataRepository extends BananaRepository` e `BananaRepository extends Repository<Banana>`, ao instanciar o `BananaPrataRepository`, o `getGenericSuperclass()` vai trazer `BananaRepository` ao invés de `Repository<Banana>`, o que te dará um `ClassCastExcepotion`.
4. Se você instanciar o `Repository<T>` diretamente, sem ser por meio de uma subclasse, o `getGenericSuperclass()` vai trazer `Object`, e ao tentar o cast para `ParameterizedType`, vai dar `ClassCastException`.
5. Se você tiver `class StrangeRepository2 extends StrangeRepository1<String>` e `class StrangeRepository1<A> extends Repository<Banana>`, o código vai vai pensar que o tipo genérico é a classe `String` ao invés da classe `Banana`. Esse caso na prática não faz sentido, mas é importante saber que em teoria pode ocorrer, e se ocorrer, o tipo genérico errado será encontrado.

A conclusão é que a classe `Repository` só pode ser usada nas seguintes condições:

- Ela só pode ser usada por meio de uma subclasse, nunca diretamente.
- As subclasses devem declarar o tipo genérico da superclasse (`Repository`) no `extends`.
- As subclasses não devem conter elas mesmas outras subclasses.

Agora vejamos o topo do seu stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at br.com.amarildo.repository.Repository.<init>(Repository.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:119)
```

Ele mostra que o Weld (responsável pelo CDI no JBoss) invocou o construtor da classe `Repository` diretamente por meio de reflection. Isso vai fazer você cair no caso 4 da lista acima.

Ou seja, no lugar onde você está injetando um `Repository<AlgumaCoisa>`, você deve fazer isso:

- Injetar um `AlgumaCoisaRepository`.
- Trabalhar com `@Qualifier`s.
- Especificar o bean correto a ser injetado no `beans.xml`.

Além disso, é possível permitir-se que as subclasses de `Repository` possam elas mesmas terem subclasses através do seguinte:

```
Class<?> directSubclass = getClass();
while (directSubclass.getSuperclass() != Repository.class) {
    directSubclass = directSubclass.getSuperclass();
}
Type genericSuper = directSubclass.getGenericSuperclass();
if (!(genericSuper instanceof ParameterizedType)) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("A superclasse definida deve conter os tipos genéricos adequados.");
Type generic = ((ParameterizedType) genericSuper).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
if (!(generic instanceof Class<?>)) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("O tipo genérico do repositório deve ser uma classe que não tenha ela memsma outro tipo genérico.");
Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) generic;
```

Além disso, a classe `Repository` deve ser abstrata.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Victor. eu vou verificar todos os passo que você me Passou .

Comment: Posteio toda a sequencia do meu código acima ainda não consegui identificar o erro caso alguém possa me dizer ta complicado. vlw

Comment: estou recebendo o seguinte erro agora = WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type TesteRepository with qualifiers @Default

Answer (score 0):

Passe a classe genérica por parâmetro no construtor

```
public Repository(EntityManager manager, Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.manager = manager;
    this.clazz = entityClass;
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Marquezani vou teste.

Comment: fiz o teste do jeito abaixo

Comment: ' @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Inject
 public Repository(EntityManager manager, Class<T> entityClass) {
  this.manager = manager;
  this.clazz = entityClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
 }'

Comment: porem me retorna o seguinte erro = WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Class<T> with qualifiers Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] Inject public br.com.amarildo.repository.Repository(EntityManager, Class<T>)
  at br.com.amarildo.repository.Repository.<init>(Repository.java:17)

Comment: Esse erro já é causado pelo Bean que você passou por parâmetro. Tente adicionar um beans.xml no WEB-INF como no link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561836/weld-001408-unsatisfied-dependencies-for-type-with-qualifiers-default-at

Comment: fiz conforme mencionado mais infelizmente o erro percisti

Comment: xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://jboss.org/schema/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd

Comment: Obrigado a todos o erro Foi resolvido conforme abaixo: eu tinha que fazer a injeção no meu metodo TesteRepository da class TesteRepository era só isso.

    @Inject
 public TesteRepository(EntityManager manager) {
  super(manager);
 }